# Check if table exists in the database - PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm new in PL SQL, and I need to check if table exist on server and drop it.

Thanks in advance,
Goran

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can query the tablenames

```
select tname from tab where tname = 'TABLE_NAME_TO_SEARCH_FOR';
```

Comment: Note that the table name must be upper case even if you have created the table without uppercase.

Answer (score 9):

```
select tname from tab where tname = 'TABLE_NAME';
```

Answer (score 7):

This is where the true power of the information schema comes in.
A simple query will point you in the right direction

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  information_schema.tables
WHERE
  table_name='salesorders';
```

This can then be used in plpg function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_exists(v_table text)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    v_count int;
    v_sql text;
BEGIN
  v_sql = 
    'SELECT ' ||
    '  count(1) ' ||
    'FROM ' ||
    '  information_schema.tables ' ||
    'WHERE ' ||
    E'  table_name=\'' || v_table || E'\'';

  EXECUTE v_sql INTO v_count;

  RETURN v_count>0;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Use the function

```
select * from table_exists('salesordesrs');
```

That should be enough to get you going.

OOPS
Seems I misread the original posters question. I've answered for PostgreSQL.

Peter.

Answer (score 6):

The most efficient method is, don't. Just drop the table. If the table didn't exist already, it'll raise an exception.

Running a query just before dropping the table is just wasting time doing what Oracle will do automatically for you.

You can handle the exception however you want, e.g.:

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE "MYTABLE"';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('the table did not exist!');
    ELSE
      RAISE;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: @user428955: no, that won't work - a bind variable cannot be used for a table name.

Comment: Are you sure?  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm seems to disagree with you.

Comment: yes, I am sure. There's nothing in that link that suggests that a *table name* can be supplied in a bind variable.

Comment: Quoted from your link: *"You cannot use bind arguments to pass the names of schema objects to a dynamic SQL statement."*

Comment: I would rather go for an if then for an exception.

Comment: @florin: there's no need for an IF here.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp thank you, you are correct I gave a bad example..what I was trying to avoid was a new person allowing a sql injection by just pipping the table name. It appears to the oracle doesn't want to allow anyone to bind because doing so is a bad idea really(because your taking a variable in for a table to remove).  

http://pastebin.com/4N5VJfcJ tested it, just to be sure..exception is thrown -SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Answer (score 3):

I had some troubles with the solutions above, as my DB has a peculiar tree structure. This should give every table in your schema:

```
SELECT
   table_name
FROM
   all_tables
WHERE
   table_name = '<your table here>'
```

Comment: Note that the table name must be upper case even if you have created the table without uppercase.